# Disable require password on Wakeup through group policy

Tags: windows-10, passwords, sleep, hibernate, group-policy

I'm trying to disable being prompted for password when the PC wakes up from Hibernate/sleep but not from a clean boot. But I'm unable to find the appropriate registry to alter or what to create.

I'm wanting to create a group policy to disable this in 50 machines running Windows 10

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7771/prevent-windows-asking-for-a-password-on-wake-up-from-sleepstandby/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant GPOs are.

`Require a password when a computer wakes (plugged in)`

`Require a password when a computer wakes (on battery)`

> If you disable this policy setting, the user is not prompted for a
>   password when the system resumes from sleep.

The settings are located here in the Group Policy Editor:

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Power Management > Sleep Settings
```

Comment: Hello w32sh,

This worked perfectly, Appreciate the timely response.

Comment: @BadAdviceBob. YW and glad that helped.

Comment: Any way to achieve the same on a consumer Windows 10? Thanks @BadAdviceBob

Comment: Did you manage to work this out? It's guide to do this is on this link.http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7771/prevent-windows-asking-for-a-password-on-wake-up-from-sleepstandby/

Comment: Apologies for such a late reply but yes I sorted the issue thank you.